# One to many inserting on wrong table

Tags: api, symfony

I have one relantionship that has one table called "*Category*" and other called "*Beer*", when i was trying to creating a new beer with category api gives me a error.

**BeerController**

```
/**
 * @Route("/", methods={"POST"})
 * @param  Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function saveAction(Request $request){

    $data_arr = json_decode($data = $request->getContent(),true);
    $beer = new Beer();
    $category = new Category();

    $beer->getCategory();
    $form = $this->createForm(BeerType::class, $beer);
    $form->submit($data_arr);

    $beer->setCategory($category);
    $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $doctrine->persist($category);
    $doctrine->merge($beer);
    $doctrine->flush();
    return new JsonResponse([$data_arr], 200);
}
```

**BeerEntity**

```
/**
 * Beer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="beers")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Beer
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="beer", cascade={"persist", "remove" }))
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $category
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

}
```

**CategoryEntity**

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Beer", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $beer;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beer = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**BeerType(form)**

```
class BeerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array 
    $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('price')
            ->add('slug')
            ->add('type')
            ->add('abv')
            ->add('brewedby')
            ->add('createdat')
            ->add('updatedat')
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => Category::class
                ]) 
   ;
```

***console.log(error)***

> "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO category (name)
>   VALUES (?)' with params [null]"
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name'
>   cannot be null"

As the problem itself says, when i was try to create a new beer with a category(already created), the controller try to create a new category, but i want to create a new beer with category already created.

**Edit:**

When i send data from beer via api, category is send normally, but when i try to push beers with a get, category isn't more on beers.

**Post Beer**

```
{abv: 7, brewedby: "Péttrin Miranda Souza", category_id: "7", description: "Descrição da cerva",…}
abv: 7
brewedby: "Péttrin Miranda Souza"
category_id: "7"
description: "Descrição da cerva"
name: "Beer"
price: "25"
slug: "mugger"
type: "Cerveja bavaria"
```

**Get Beer**

```
5: {id: 19, name: "Beer", description: "Descrição da cerva", price: 25, slug: "mugger",…}
abv: 7
brewedby: "Péttrin Miranda Souza"
createdat: "2019-05-20T09:28:08-03:00"
description: "Descrição da cerva"
id: 19
name: "Beer"
price: 25
slug: "mugger"
type: "Cerveja bavaria"
updatedat: "2019-05-20T09:28:08-03:00"
```

Comment: Read the error message and then ask yourself where the category name is being set. Hint: it's not.

Comment: Now paying more attention sounds like i'm stupid xD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the category entity already selected in the form, there is no need to instantiate a category entity or persist that in your action (the encountered error comes from creating a new instance and persisting that - instead of using the existing category reference that is connected to the beer entity in the form data binding). You can try with the following action version:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", methods={"POST"})
 * @param  Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function saveAction(Request $request){

    $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $data_arr = json_decode($data = $request->getContent(),true);
    $beer = new Beer();

    $form = $this->createForm(BeerType::class, $beer);
    $form->submit($data_arr);

    $category = $doctrine->getRepository(Category::class)->find($data_arr['category_id']);
    $beer->setCategory($category);

    $doctrine->persist($beer);
    $doctrine->flush();

    return new JsonResponse([$data_arr], 200);
}
```

Updated the answer after the additional comments. So now the category is explicitly fetched based on the given parameter id. Another solution - where the previous simple controller code without any special fetching for category - would be to use form data transformer ([symfony data transormer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#harder-example-transforming-an-issue-number-into-an-issue-entity)) that would automatically map the int id into category object.

Comment: Works, but category it's not sending on the requisition.

Comment: What do you mean by "requisition"? It is not stored into the database id field - or not sent back via the response? Or something else?

Comment: Requisition from Api, category is sending from api normally, i'll be edit my question, see if you understand.

Comment: ok, I updated the answer accordingly. Basically for this you have two options: fetching the category explicitly in the action (as done in the updated answer) or creating a data transformer to the form that would automatically map the id to the entity (in which case the form submit would be making the entity connection and thus the controller code wouldn't need to handle category entity).

Comment: Hnmm, i think i'm understanding, i'ts hard for a front-end developer, work's fine your answer!